# Meteor: Redirect to another url using Meteor.go('url') meeting error

Tags: javascript, meteor

In this javascript code, I will submit a form to server, and waiting response data. After I get response from server, I will redirect to `/list`

```
Template.post_question_form.events({
    'submit form' : function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // get content value
        var question = event.target.question_title.value;
        var content = event.target.question_content.value;
        // send data to server
        Meteor.call('createQuestion', question, content, function(error, result) {
            console.log(result);
            Meteor.go('list');
        });
    }
});
```

But when my web application runs to line `Meteor.go('list')`. I meet exception:

```
Exception in delivering result of invoking 'createQuestion': TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at http://localhost:3000/client/views/post_question/post_question_form.js?ea61f464a8905bc8789871133dddf7b0782e7438:39:20
    at Meteor.bindEnvironment [as _callback] (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?81e2f06cff198adaa81b3bc09fc4f3728b7370ec:977:22)
    at _.extend._maybeInvokeCallback (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?41b62dcceb3ce0de6ca79c6aed088cccde6a44d8:3858:12)
    at _.extend.receiveResult (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?41b62dcceb3ce0de6ca79c6aed088cccde6a44d8:3878:10)
    at _.extend._livedata_result (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?41b62dcceb3ce0de6ca79c6aed088cccde6a44d8:4931:9)
    at onMessage (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?41b62dcceb3ce0de6ca79c6aed088cccde6a44d8:3723:12)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?41b62dcceb3ce0de6ca79c6aed088cccde6a44d8:2717:11
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:156:11)
    at _.extend._launchConnection.self.socket.onmessage (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?41b62dcceb3ce0de6ca79c6aed088cccde6a44d8:2716:11)
```

And here is `createQuestion` code:

```
Meteor.methods({
   'createQuestion': function(title, content) {
       // insert into database question object
       return Topic.insert({
            title: title,
            content: content
        });
   }
});
```

Although I have tested `localhost:3000/list`, no problem founds. I don't know how to solve this problem.

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you include your server-side method? The 'createQuestion' method.

Comment: @arnonate I have commented all code inside `createQuestion` for testing, but still meet same error. So I don't think the problem here. Anyway, I have added this method to my question. Please review. Thanks :)

Comment: Looks like an issue with your Meteor method. Check your server-side logs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need `Router.go()` if you are using Iron Router. I don't know of a `Meteor.go()` - Meteor does not ship with a router.

Comment: oh. very dummy error. thanks very much :D I google at some source, but maybe because copy-paste error :)